# How to list articles in user node

Tags: nodes, users

On the user node page, how to automatically show the articles posted by the user?

Comment: What do you mean with "user node page"?

Answer (score 2):

In short, the [Views module](http://drupal.org/project/views) can be used to do that. [This question and answer from the main StackOverflow site covers the same issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7057718/drupal-7-view-to-list-content-created-by-logged-in-user), including a link to a [tutorial with more details](http://vimeo.com/26264712).

Start by installing the Views module. Create a new view to list content. Under the Advanced section for the view, add UID as a contextual filter. From there, you can either create a block display or a page display, to output the view. If you add a page display, you could have it appear as a tab on the user's page, by setting it as a "Menu tab."

Comment: Just noticed the link to the Tutorial goes to 404.

Comment: This might be the video that Link was pointing to http://vimeo.com/26264712

Answer (score 1):

**Note:** user page is not a node; it is stored in different tables and not in *node* or *node%*.

I'm assuming you want to list the articles that a user creates on his/her user page. Drupal core has a module called **Tracker** which does exactly what you want. Enable it and you'll be able to see the articles a user creates on the url http://drupalsite.com/user/%uid/track (%uid being the userid of the user).